# How Read a text file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I want to read the file %i.txt and save the content in cadena1.

This is my code

```
NSMutableString *b = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i];
[b appendString:@".txt"];

//Assing b to a Nsstring

NSString *cadena1 = b;
NSLog(@"The text is:%@", cadena1);
```

The problem is that i don't know how save the content of the files txt into NSString. In console with ---> NSLog(@"Cadena de archivo de texto:%@", cadena1);
Cadena de archivo de texto: %i.text.

I try with:

```
NSString *b = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSMutableString        stringWithFormat:@"%i", i] ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *cadena1 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:b encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding    error:NULL];
NSLog(@"Cadena de archivo de texto:%@", cadena1);
```

but this is the result

Cadena de archivo de texto:{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1138\cocoasubrtf510 {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;} {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;} \paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0 \pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx623‌​6\tx6803\pardirnatural \f0\fs24 \cf0 ME PARECE UNA MALA OPCION NO GANAMOS NADA}.

Best regards

Comment: It would be helpful if your comments were in english. Getting used to english comments is a good idea anyway, because some day you might join a team, and the lingua franca in IT is english.

Comment: What's wrong with the NSString `initWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:` method?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The question is not about what the title describes. In fact, I have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: @middaparka He/She doesn't understands, that this method must be called. It's an entertaining question, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear!

"Save": Data (e.g. `NSSTring`) to File (e.g. *.txt)

"Read": File (e.g. *.txt) to Data (e.g. `NSSTring`)

---

You create a `NSMutableString`:

```
NSMutableString *b = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i];
[b appendString:@".txt"];
```

And then you assign `b` to `cadena1`:

```
NSString *cadena1 = b;
NSLog(@"Cadena de archivo de texto:%@", cadena1);
```

It's logical that you don't have your file content in the variable `cadena1`, because you never did read the content of the file. You just created a string which holds the name of the file.

If your file `%i.txt` is within the mainBundle (in Xcode):

```
NSString *b = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i] ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *cadena1 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:b encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
NSLog(@"Cadena de archivo de texto:%@", cadena1);
```

---

If your file `%i.txt` is within the documents-folder:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *b = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]];
NSString *cadena1 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:b encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL]; 
NSLog(@"Cadena de archivo de texto:%@", cadena1);
```

Comment: With the first solution, ----> cadena1 = Cadena de archivo de texto:{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1138\cocoasubrtf510
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\pardirnatural

\f0\fs24 \cf0 ME PARECE UNA MALA OPCION NO GANAMOS NADA}.             What is wrong?

Comment: Is this file really available and added to your target?

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:`

If you don't feel this answer is appropriate then please reword your question. Especially make your question and code sniplet actually match the subject line.

However, it may well be that you are really in search for `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:` but that I can only guess.